# Joomla breadcrumbs problem

Tags: plugins, joomla, breadcrumbs

I am using Joomla 1.5x and I am using breadcrumbs. I would like to have full path with my breadcrumb, but I can't have it. I have main menu on the top of the page and submenu on the side, and when I click on submenu item, I get only Home>> subcategory name

I am not sure what the problem is and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably are using 2 different menus, one for the the top and one for the sidebar. In order to get - Home >> Main Menu >> Submenu all of the menu items need to be in the same menu.

In order to do this, you will need to combine your main and sidebar menus in to a single menu. Then when you set up your modules, for the top you need to set the start level to 0 and the end level to 1 with child menu display turned off. Then you will need another module for the sidebar. In this module, set it to display the same menu as the main, then set the start level and end level to 1. This will cause Joomla to only display the first level children of the active parent. It will also correct your breadcrumb problem.

Answer (score 0):

Submenu on the side is child menu from your main menu on the top?
If yes, you can use alias, you can find it in MENUS > YOUR_SIDEBAR_NAME > ALIAS

If you no, you should make a main category first for your subcategory but don't put the main category in your submenu, just put the subcategory use the alias